# How to remove element of Javascript Array with safe method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a code :

```
myarray[150] = 'a';
myarray[80] = 'b';
myarray[122] = 'c';
```

And then :

```
myarray.splice(80, 1);
myarray[80] = 'b';
```

The result of my code above on my application is :

> [150] = 'a'; [80] = 'b'; [121] = 'c';

I don't understand why `c` value have `121` as index. Can anyonen explain what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Don't use sparse arrays, there is always a better data structure than a sparse array. Use an object (e.g. dictionary), or an array of objects.

Comment: @adam : can you give example?

Comment: `myarray = {150:'a',80:'b',122:'c'}` In this case, simply do `delete myarray[80]` (or `myarray[80] = null`). An alternative data structure is an array of objects:  `myarray = []; myarray.push({id:150,value:'a'}),myarray.push({id:80,value:'b'}),myarray.push({id:122,value:'c'})`

Comment: @adam : your solution look similar with one of the answer below. And that's idea working well so thank you for solution.

Comment: It's not the same at all. In your situation, you have an array of length `150` with the vast majority of the items being undefined. In my example, I have an object with 3 items in it, and I delete one of them.

Comment: @Michael not quite right. Both are using delete, but Adams point is to not use an Array but an Object, wich mike isnt suggesting

Comment: @jonas-w : which one the safest way?

Comment: Back to my original comment - don't use a sparse array.

Comment: its both "safe". but the design adam suggested is more wisely...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use:

```
delete myarray[80]
```

for safe delete

Comment: This code running well. @Adam What do you think about his solution ?

Comment: @Michael This solves your problem exactly as state it, but sparse arrays are an anti-pattern when there are better data structures that solve your problem. I'm downvoting this, not because it's incorrect, but because it's promoting a bad practice.

Comment: Note that a sparse array is automatically allocated to the length that encloses the assigned element with the highest index (150 in this case). This means that as long as you load `myarray` with more elements, in whatever order, `myarray.length` keeps track of the element with the highest assigned index for you. If you happen to `delete` that element, however, `myarray.length` remains unchanged, and you must adjust it manually if you need it to retain that tracking behavior after element deletion.

Comment: Interesting insights on the topic: https://remysharp.com/2018/06/26/an-adventure-in-sparse-arrays

Answer (score 6):

This line of code removes one element of the array at index 80. Thus, all elements after 80 would be shifted down one index:

```
myarray.splice(80, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use splice twice:

```
myarray.splice(80, 1);
myarray.splice(80, 0,"b");
```

Or you dont remove, but override to null/undefined

```
myarray[80]=undefined;
```

However this array will consist of 117 "undefined" wich is, as adam stated an antipattern. May do this:

```
var myarray={};
myarray[80]="b";
delete myarray[80];
```

It has just one element, and is therefore not memory consuming.

Comment: Is this an approach you would use in an application? Or is this just something that would solve the OP's problem exactly as they stated it? The problem posters are trying to solve and the solution they are asking for are seldom the same.

Comment: @Adam so you wanna suggest me to copy+paste your upper comment and steel your idea?

Comment: No, it'd probably be better if you just deleted this as an answer, because, while it's not incorrect, it's of low quality.

Comment: @Adam, like all answers above, that are actually not answering the question, but just identifying the problem

Comment: You're right, I should go through and downvote all of them, not just the first one I downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Because When you initiated c on index 122, and then removed one element fron your array, Its length changed and the latest index is now 121 not 122

Comment: Also this code myArray[80] = 'b' after splice doesn't add new element to table, just change existing one

Answer (score 0):

As the [`Array.prototype.splice()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) specifies, the second parameter is the number of elements to be deleted.

Thus, when doing

```
myarray.splice(80, 1);
```

You are only removing one element, at position 80.

`"c"` gets moved one index to the left.

---

Furthermore, doing

```
myarray[80] = 'b';
```

does not add another element, but changes the value of an already existing one.

Answer (score 0):

.splice() removes an array element, but does not make it empty. Therefore, the index change and 'c' has an index of '121'

More about it you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)